# CSS styling of Wordpress "bbp style pack" Widget

Tags: css

Please look [here](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/):

This is the CSS for the Latest Forum Activity widget:

```
.widget_display_topics ul {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.66666667em;
}
a.bsp-la-reply-topic-title {
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.bsp-la-text,.bsp-la-topic-author, .bsp-activity-freshness, .bsp-activity-forum {
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.widget_display_topics ul:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a HTML snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a class="bsp-la-reply-topic-title" href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk">
    How is the the “Student Roles” attribute in the XML data file defined?</a>
    <div class="bsp-activity-author">
        <span class="bsp-la-text">topic by</span>
        <span class="bsp-la-topic-author topic-author">
        <a class="bbp-author-link" href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk" title="View TS-Support's profile">
        <span class="bbp-author-avatar">
        <img alt="" class="avatar avatar-14 photo" height="14" itemprop="image" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com" width="14"></span><span class="bbp-author-name">TS-Support</span></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bsp-activity-freshness">
        <span class="bsp-la-freshness">4 days, 4 hours ago</span></div>
    <div class="bsp-activity-forum">
        <span class="bsp-la-text">in </span>
        <a class="bsp-la-forum-title bbp-forum-title" href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk">
        Midweek Editor</a> </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am unsure about two issues:

[image: Styles]

- How do I align the avatar more nicely?
- Can I bring the "IN FAQ" up so that it flows nicely after the duration? Eg:

> "4 months ago in FAQ"

Answer (score 0):

This is only half of the answer:

## Avatar Position

```
.widget_display_topics img.avatar.photo {
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

## Flowing the information

By using `:before` and `:after` I was able to add the `/` delimiter with relvant styling. And by using the right combinations of `display: block;` and `display: inline;` it yeilds the expected results:

[image: Updated Display]

The final CSS for the Widget:

```
/* Recent Topics Widget */
/* See also: .widget_display_topics img.avatar.photo */
.widget_display_topics ul {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.66666667em;
}
a.bsp-la-reply-topic-title {
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
}
.bsp-la-text,
.bsp-la-topic-author,
.bsp-activity-freshness,
.bsp-activity-forum {
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.bsp-activity-author,
.bsp-activity-freshness,
.bsp-activity-forum {
    display: inline;
}
.bsp-activity-author:after,
.bsp-activity-forum > .bsp-la-text:before {
    content:"/";
    margin: 0 7px;
}
.widget_display_topics ul:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

However, I don't know if the values `-3px` and `4px` would always be the correct values? But it now looks good for me.